# How to index just those models\rows, where some_field=some_value?

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, django-oscar

I use django-oscar + Solr + haystack.

```
*===============================================================================================================*
|   id  | partner_sku|price_currency|price_excl_tax|num_in_stock|date_created|date_updated|partner_id|product_id|
|"10451"|"S0010436"  |  "USD"       |   74.00      |    20      |'some_date' |'some_date' |     1    | 5992     |
|"10452"|"S0010436"  |  "USD"       |   80.00      |     0      |'some_date' |'some_date' |     2    | 5992     |
*===============================================================================================================*
```

I want to index just those rows where `partner_id=2`. `index_queryset` below does not do what I need, because other partners also indexed.

```
class ProductIndexes(CelerySearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(
            document=True, use_template=True,
            template_name='search/indexes/cpu/item_text.txt')

    upc = indexes.CharField(model_attr="upc", null=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title', null=True)

    # Fields for faceting
    product_class = indexes.CharField(null=True, faceted=True)
    category = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True, faceted=True)
    partner = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True, faceted=True)
    price = indexes.FloatField(null=True, faceted=True)
    vendor = indexes.CharField(null=True, faceted=True)
    rating = indexes.IntegerField(null=True, faceted=True)
    num_in_stock = indexes.BooleanField(null=True, faceted=True)

    # Spelling suggestions
    suggestions = indexes.FacetCharField()

    date_created = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_created')
    date_updated = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_updated')

    def get_model(self):
        return get_model('catalogue', 'Product')

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(stockrecords__partner_id=2).order_by('-num_in_stock')
```

`python manage.py rebuild_index` is executed

How to implement indexing which I need?

Comment: As long as it doesn't work for you, your solution "seems" to be incorrect. Try to understand what are your attempts about, why and how you're going to achieve it. It's a problem to suggest you anything useful based on 'seems/should' concept, with only chunks of code available. Whilst I understand it's impossible to post everything Django stuff here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the same issue: [django oscar github issue 2169](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/2169)
As you're trying to filter on the `num_in_stock` which is a `BooleanField`????

i'd recommend changing this to an IntegerField and adding a `prepare_num_in_stock function like so:

```
def prepare_num_in_stock(self, obj)
    # define get_local_stock as you please
    return int(obj.get_local_stock())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: About `BooleanField`. Yes, strange. This code I got from previous developer.